# Using column index, how to copy specific columns

Tags: excel, vba

New day, new problem.
I have received much help, and hope you can help me with this too. Have searched around for solutions to my problem but not found.

Here is my code:

```
SearchString = "start"
    Set aCell = phaseRange.Find(What:=SearchString, LookIn:=xlValues, _
            LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
            MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
    Set bCell = aCell
    ReDim Preserve arrStart(nS)
    arrStart(nS) = aCell.Row
    nS = nS + 1
    Do While ExitLoop = False
        Set aCell = phaseRange.FindNext(After:=aCell)
        If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
            If aCell.Row = bCell.Row Then Exit Do
            ReDim Preserve arrStart(nS)
            arrStart(nS) = aCell.Row
            nS = nS + 1
        Else
            ExitLoop = True
        End If
    Loop
Else
End If
```

And to write it out:

```
For i = 1 To nS - 1
        Sheets("DataSheet").Select
        Sheets("raw_list").Rows(arrStart(i)).Copy
        Cells(i, 1).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
Next
```

As you see, I seek in a column for a String. When I get a result, row number is stored in an array. In the next code snippet, I write out hits in entire rows. Is it possible that instead of taking the entire row, choose which columns in that row you want to copy in a simple way?

Grateful for assistance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already know the Column number and you have the rows in array then try this

```
Sheets("raw_list").Cells(arrStart(i),5).Copy
```

This will copy the cell from the 5th Column (Col E) in a specific row.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you. But have tried to add more columns. Tried to change it to a .Range but can't get it to work.

Comment: Also tried with a .Union. But it doesn't work (as I have written it)
`Sheets("raw_list").Union(Cells(arrStart(i), NameCol), Cells(arrStart(i), PhaseCol)).Copy`

Comment: Use `Range` instead of `Union` :)

Comment: But if I use Range I will get the cells that are between, right? I wasn't clear that the cells that i wanted copied isn't besides eachother. :/ Will I be able to achive that?

Comment: Yes in that case what you were doing was correct. but you have to modify it like this `Union(Sheets("raw_list").Cells(arrStart(i), NameCol), Sheets("raw_list").Cells(arrStart(i), PhaseCol)).Copy`